# Lambda to std::function compiles in clang but not in gcc

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I have learnt that a lambda and `std::function` are different types. I also know that a captureless lambda can be converted to a pointer to a function. But then I wrote the following program that *compiles with clang but rejected by gcc*. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/79hrndn3E)

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int func() 
{ 
    return 5; 
}
int main()  
{
    
    std::function<const int&()> getter1 = 
                                        [] { return func(); }; //gcc rejects but clang accepts  
    getter1();
}
```

Gcc says:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:12:41: error: conversion from 'main()::<lambda()>' to non-scalar type 'std::function<const int&()>' requested
   12 |                                         [] { return func(); }; //gcc rejects but clang accepts
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

While msvc gives a warning:

```
 warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary
Compiler returned: 0
```

Is gcc right in rejecting the program or clang in accepting it?

Comment: `[] { return func(); }` returns `int`, so looks like clang is wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gcc is now correct in rejecting the code, as of [P2255](https://wg21.link/p2255) which added a new type trait to detect when references are bound to temporaries.

The problem with this declaration:

```cpp
std::function<const int&()> getter1 = [] { return func(); };
```

is that `getter1()` is unconditional undefined behavior.

This is exactly analogous to this case:

```cpp
const int& oops() { return func(); }
```

We're binding a reference to a temporary `int`, which immediately goes out of scope before the function even returns, so any attempt to read from the reference is undefined.

Except that compilers have warned about `oops` for a while, and only now have the tools to also warn about `getter1`. Which is great!